# Android, what to save in my database if I use Facebook or Google+ login to enter my app?

Tags: android, facebook, google-plus

So, in a typical flow a user should first log in by entering a set of required fields, such as username and password, and in this application I would like to associate other objects with this user for customized UI experience.

Now assuming that the user chose to log in using Facebook, then what is the best field to save instead of password and username? Is Facebook or even Google user id a good choice?

Please note that logging in using Facebook or Google is a special type of login and there is no way that another user (Jack for example) can enter the Facebook user id of another user (John) and enter his account. In essence, entering the user id of any other user as a password or username is useless because these fields are ignored when logging in using either Facebook or Google.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Facebook User IDs and Google User IDs are unique so this makes them suitable to be saved as unique user identifiers in your database.